# What is wrong with this sql where-clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select, date, where-clause

I am selecting records based on two dates in a same column but my where condition fails to select records on the `StartDate` and `EndDate`...

`where CreatedDate between @StartDate and @EndDate`

I get only the records inbetween the dates and not the records on the `StartDate` and `EndDate`... Consider if I pass the same date as `StartDate` and `EndDate` I should be able to select all the records on that date. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any time component attached?

Comment: @gbn i hav time component attached

Comment: I assume this is a date/time column. Could the times be throwing you off (i.e. between 6/3/2010 0:00:00 and 6/3/2010 0:00:00). Nothing would come back in this case.

Comment: Your inputs are probably not what you think they are.

Answer (score 3):

From the MSDN page about [`BETWEEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx):

> BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression  and less than or equal to the value of end_expression.

I would say that the `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` are probably not what you think they are - the `DateTime` datatype include hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds and these should also be specified if you want consistent results.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749615/does-ms-sql-servers-between-include-the-range-boundaries/749663#749663) answer for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

`BETWEEN` *is* inclusive. What are the dates you're specifying? Remember that `DATETIME` is accurate to the millisecond so if your dates are off by a millisecond then you won't pick up the "equal to" part.

You should be able to manually adjust @StartDate and @EndDate to do what you want like so:

```
SET @StartDate = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@StartDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
SET @EndDate = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@StartDate AS FLOAT) + 1) AS DATETIME)

...
WHERE
   CreatedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: Why? This is exactly what between does

Answer (score 1):

see this question: [Does MS SQL Server's "between" include the range boundaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749615/does-ms-sql-servers-between-include-the-range-boundaries); I think your problem may be the time as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749615/does-ms-sql-servers-between-include-the-range-boundaries/749663#749663)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that SQL Server DATETIME includes the time component, and **if you don't specify a time, it defaults to midnight** -- and midnight is the first instant of that day.

In practical terms, if you said `BETWEEN '6/3/2010' AND '6/4/2010'` then the only records from 6/4 you'll see are those that occurred on 6/4/2010 at 00:00:00. If you've got a record on 6/4 at 12:34 it won't be returned.

The best fix is probably to (A) use explicit > and <; and (B) use date math to get the right endpoint if you're only using dates without times. E.g.:

```
WHERE order_date >= @StartDate
AND   order_date <  CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@StartDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have time attached to the date. If yes, try to convert or cast it. 
OR Possibly you are storing date in a Varchar Column.

Between clause will return TRUE if the records are FROM the start date and the END date 
Which mean it includes the START and END date.