# Query to return data from SQL Server table based on date criteria

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have the following piece of code in C# that I use to select some rows from a SQL Server table based on a date criteria.

```
DateTime From, DateTime To
SqlParameter[] oParam = new SqlParameter[3];
oParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@From", From.Date);
oParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@To", To.Date);
DataTable dt = clsDatabaseHistory.ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM tblHistory WHERE Date_Requested BETWEEN @From and @To", oParam);
```

If for example `From=18/08/2011` and `To=18/08/2011` and there is data in the table `tblHistory` that has the `Date_Requested` value as `18/08/2011` the query does not return it.

But if I change the value of `To` from `18/08/2011` to `To=19/08/2011` the query returns me all the values from the table that have a `Date_Requested` value of `18/08/2011`, but none from the `19/08/2011`.

How can something like that be possible and what query should I use to return rows where the date field is between date1 and date2.

Something like :

```
select * rows where datevalue >= date1 and datevalue <= date2
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749615/does-ms-sql-servers-between-include-the-range-boundaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to use >= and <

```
select * rows where datevalue >= date1 and datevalue < date2 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`From.Date` and `To.Date` gets the date portion on c# side ignoring the time portion; you need to do something similar on the database side.

Try

```
"SELECT * FROM tblHistory WHERE cast(Date_Requested as DATE) BETWEEN @From and @To"
```

to remove the time portion.

EDIT:
      as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749615/does-ms-sql-servers-between-include-the-range-boundaries/749663#749663), you could change `@To` param value to

```
      oParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@To", To.Date.AddDays(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet your Date_Requested in your table also has some time associated with it - so it probably really is `18/08/2011 14:37` or something like that.

The `BETWEEN` clause will be selecting anything between `18/08/2011 00:00:00` and `18/08/2011 00:00:00` - basically nothing.

What you need to take into account when working with `DATETIME` is the fact there's always also `TIME` involved!

If you want everything for today, you need to use:

```
BETWEEN `18/08/2011 00:00:00` AND `18/08/2011 23:59:59`
```

With those two values, you **should** get all rows with a `Date_Requested` of today.

**OR:** in SQL Server 2008 and newer, you could also use the `DATE` column type which stores date only - no time portion involved. In that case, you should be fine with your query values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for time (not just date).  One way I handle that is like this:

```
SELECT
...
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(8), date_begin, 112) <= convert(varchar(8), @to, 112)
```

This converts dates to `YYYYMMDD` format (with no time), which is very easy to use in `<, >, =` comparrisons.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to you all, i've done the following thing

```
oParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@To", To.Date.AddDays(1));
```

and used the following select

```
SELECT * from MyTable WHERE CONVERT(varchar(8), Date_Requested, 112) >= CONVERT(varchar(8), @From, 112) and CONVERT(varchar(8), Date_Requested, 112) < CONVERT(varchar(8), @To, 112)
```

Datetime variables must be converted to be compared.

Thanks all!