# MySQL - BETWEEN will not select correct results

Tags: mysql, select, date, between

I am trying to select rows that are in between two dates. First, here is my data:

```
punch_id    eid     time    unixtime    punch_type  day     date        doy
135          2      12:53   1314723193  0            4   08/28/2011     241  
134          2      12:53   1314723190  3            4   08/31/2011     241
133          2      12:53   1314723187  2            4   08/20/2011     241
132          2      12:52   1314723125  1            4   08/30/2011     241
```

I have tried these two queries.

```
SELECT * FROM `punches` WHERE `date` >= '08/20/11' AND `date` <= '08/31/11'

SELECT * FROM `punches` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '08/20/11' AND '08/31/11'
```

Neither of these select the rows containing the date 08/31/11. It selects the 08/20/11 ones though. I tried to use it another way and when I run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `punches` WHERE `date` >= '08/10/11' AND `date` <= '08/20/11'
```

I again do not get the correct result: the 20th is left out once again. What is the problem with the way I am executing this?

Comment: How is your date column defined? With or without the hh:mm:ss part?

Comment: The application simply outputs it in the format listed. MM/DD/YY

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080824/mysql-between-clause-not-inclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749615/does-ms-sql-servers-between-include-the-range-boundaries/749663#749663) question.

As others have mentioned, your primary problem is not accounting for the time. A few options to handle that:

1. Use a function to convert the DateTime to a Date. I don't recommend this option, since it will likely make the function [non-sargeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable/799616#799616).
2. Expand your `BETWEEN` to explicitly include the last moment of the day: (note: this is the latest possible value that MS SQL can store, don't know if MySQL has the same value)

   ```
   SELECT * FROM `punches` WHERE `date` 
   BETWEEN '08/20/11 00:00:00.000' AND '08/31/11 23:59:59.997'
   ```
3. Use a `<` for the upper value

   ```
   SELECT * FROM `punches` WHERE `date` >= '08/20/11' AND `date` < '09/01/11'
   ```

I actually think that last one is easier, in most situations.

I suppose you could do other things, like change the datatype of the column, but I've assumed here that you're just interested in changing the query.

** Disclaimer: I'm a MS SQL guy, not MySQL

Comment: That works, but is pretty much a 'hack', and would require a lot of work to make the application add a day to all queries. I'd rather fix it and do it right by changing the date format or something to make it work.

Comment: @Devin, if needed you could do something like `where 'date' between "2011-08-20" and  date_add( "2011-08-31" , interval 1 day)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know mysql, but in other RDBMS, dates are assuming a time part of 12 AM.  If you want to include the high date, add 1 to the day.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `date` field of type `DATE` or `DATETIME`?

It probably has to do with the time of day. If you have a `DATETIME` stored as

```
2011-08-31 13:00:00
```

then it won't match on

```
BETWEEN '08/20/11' AND '08/31/11'
```

You'd have to use

```
BETWEEN '08/20/11' AND '09/01/11'
```

The [MySQL docs for between](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) say it matches "less than or equal to" max, so it is probably the time of day throwing you off.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't specify a time with the date, then 00:00:00 is implied. Therefore the real query that the database is doing is more like...

```
SELECT * FROM `punches` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '08/20/11 00:00:00' AND '08/31/11 00:00:00'
```

Therefore a punch on 08/31/2011 at 12:53 will not get included. I think this should work, and is a bit more elegant than adding a day to the end date...

```
SELECT * FROM `punches` WHERE DATE(`date`) BETWEEN '2011-08-20' AND '2011-08-31'
```

Comment: I think you meant to include a time (23:59:59) on the corrected query?

Comment: Note the DATE() function - this converts the DATETIME to a DATE, with the time component effectively set to 00:00:00.

Comment: That query actually returned zero results.

Comment: Not sure about MySQL, but in MS SQL, that function in the WHERE clause would mean that it couldn't use any indexes.

Comment: I'm not sure why the original query somewhat worked -- shouldn't we be using YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: Try using YYYY-MM-DD format: 
SELECT * FROM `punches` WHERE DATE(`date`) BETWEEN '2011-08-20' AND '2011-08-31'