# SQL: retrieve records between dates in all databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I would like to select all the records in a table between two dates. I have a query like:

`SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE (thedate BETWEEN DATE('2012-04-01') AND DATE('2012-06-30'))`

This is fine for HSQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, but it doesn't work in SQL Server due to the lack of the Date function. Is there a way to get this to work generally for all databases (including SQL Server) or do I need to use an ORM like Hibernate (I know I should, but I'm specifically asking if this can be done in SQL)?

Comment: This should work with ANSI compliant databases. 

SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE (thedate BETWEEN '20120401' AND '20120630')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the Date(...) as far as i can tell. This example seems to work

```
DECLARE @TheDate Date = '2012-07-01';

SELECT 'hello' WHERE (@TheDate BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-06-30')
--None returned
SET @TheDate = '2012-05-01'

SELECT 'hello' WHERE (@TheDate BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-06-30')
--selects hello
```

**Edit** Btw worth looking at [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749615/does-ms-sql-servers-between-include-the-range-boundaries) with the date time answer (will post here just to save effort)

The between statement can cause issues with range boundaries for dates as

```
BETWEEN '01/01/2009' AND '01/31/2009'
```

is really interpreted as

```
BETWEEN '01/01/2009 00:00:00' AND '01/31/2009 00:00:00'
```

so will miss anything that occurred during the day of Jan 31st. In this case, you will have to use:

```
myDate >= '01/01/2009 00:00:00' AND myDate < '02/01/2009 00:00:00'  --CORRECT!
```

or

```
BETWEEN '01/01/2009 00:00:00' AND '01/31/2009 23:59:59' --WRONG! (see update!)
```

UPDATE: It is entirely possible to have records created within that last second of the day, with a datetime as late as 01/01/2009 23:59:59.997!!

For this reason, the `BETWEEN (firstday) AND (lastday 23:59:59)` approach is not recommended.

Use the `myDate >= (firstday) AND myDate < (Lastday+1)` approach instead.

Answer (score 0):

in sql-server I think you may want to look into the

```
DATEADD ( datepart , number, date )
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

but I think you're looking for

```
CAST ( expression AS data_type )
```

or

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

usage:

```
Select * from myTable where  thedateToCompare >= CONVERT ( datetime , "dd/mm/yy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM" ) and thedateToCompare <= CONVERT ( datetime , "dd/mm/yy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM" )
```

something that may change your approach is weather your source 'thedate' column type datetime, smalldatetime or is it stored in a column defined as string?

You may want to check out [a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226030%28v=sql.80%29)! for more detial on datetime constants that you could use for your string variations.