# select a row based on a particular condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
CustID     VisitTime
 1         2012-12-31 11:59
 1         2013-1-1 00:00
 1         2013-1-1 00:05
 2         2013-1-1 00:20
 2         2013-1-1 10:00
 3         2013-1-1 11:40
```

Now, I want to choose those new customers whose visited the site from `Jan 1st 12:00AM` to `Jan 31st 11:59pm`.

For example: `cust ID 1` also visited in `Dec`, hence `cust ID 1` should not be selected. Only `2` and `3` should be selected.

How do I incorporate this logic using `t-sql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTID
FROM T as T1
WHERE VisitTime between '2013-01-01 00:00' AND '2013-01-31 23:59'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT T.CustID FROM T 
                       WHERE T.CustId=T1.CustId and VisitTime < '2013-01-01')
```

Comment: You should also add some explanation, it is usually better than a code-only answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECt t.CustID
FROM Table1 t
GROUP BY t.CustID
HAVING MIN(VisitTime) >='01/01/2013 00:00:00' AND MIN(VisitTime) < '02/01/2013 00:00:00'
--same test on MAX(vistTime) if needed
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd0f3/2)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight hmmm, was just referring to http://stackoverflow.com/a/749663/961526 . Wrong, or ?

Comment: Oops, you're right, somehow I thought this was MySQL with its one second precision. In SQL Server with the `>= ... AND <` is better.