# Between Operator issue

Tags: mysql, sql-server

tblEmployee

```
ID  Name  Salary
1   E1    10000
2   E2    20000
3   E3    30000
4   E4    40000
5   E5    50000
```

Query:

```
select * from tblEmployee where Salary between 10000 AND 40000
```

Output:

```
1   E1    10000
2   E2    20000
3   E3    30000
4   E4    40000
```

But when I use the below query, I got no results. Why?

```
select * from tblEmployee where Salary between 40000 AND 10000
```

Comment: Thats how it should be between lower range to higher range.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749615/does-ms-sql-servers-between-include-the-range-boundaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between has the syntax:

```
val BETWEEN low AND high
```

And is syntactic sugar for:

```
val >= low AND val <= high
```

So your results are expected, since it is impossible for any value to be greater than 40000 *and* less than 10000.

Answer (score 1):

Between used for the range. We have to define from starting point (low value) to ending point(high value) always to get result.

So as not get the result, the reason is high to low not work. Even though for text search it always apply the same rule.
Some example which works i.e.

```
BETWEEN 10 AND 20     
BETWEEN 'C' AND 'M'
BETWEEN #07/04/1996# AND #07/09/1996#;
```

[The BETWEEN operator selects values within a range. The values can be numbers, text, or dates.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187922.aspx