# sql query to get records between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Id   | Status | Value  | CreatedDateTime
-----+--------+--------+------------------------
1    | Open   | Y      | 2014-12-10 14:03:10.100
2    | Open   | Y      | 2014-12-10 13:03:10.100
3    | Open   | N      | 2014-12-10 13:01:12.100
4    | Open   | Y      | 2014-12-10 05:02:11.100
5    | Open   | N      | 2014-12-09 15:03:10.100
6    | Open   | N      | 2014-12-08 14:03:10.100
7    | Open   | Y      | 2014-12-08 14:03:10.100
```

I wants to write a SQL query to get the records from `2014-12-08 14:03:10.100` to `2014-12-10 14:03:10.100` and also the `Status` should be `Open` with `Value = Y`.

I tried below sql query-

```
select * 
from mytable 
where CreatedDateTime between '2014-12-08 14:03:10.100' and '2014-12-10 14:03:10.100' 
  and Status in ('Open') and Value='Y'
```

Comment: I am not sure how to post table data on stackoevrflow site. Someone please correct my table..thanks

Comment: So what is the problem here?

Comment: Thanks for using stack overflow, Syed. I recommend you start looking at the "SELECT" keyword and the "WHERE" keyword.

Comment: Please show your attempts at solving this and the errors you see as it's pretty basic SQL. You're more likely to learn something if we can point out where you're going wrong rather than just giving you the answer.

Comment: It's simple. Just google for date between and where clause and you will get the answer.

Comment: Your SQL works fine: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59dfb/1** although I would change the `IN` clause to `Status = 'Open'` unless you plan to include more values. Please extend your question if something is missed by that example fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
SELECT Id,Status,Value,CreatedDateTime FROM <table>
WHERE CreatedDateTime BETWEEN '2014-12-08 14:03:10.100' AND '2014-12-10 14:03:10.100'
AND
Status = 'Open'
AND
Value = 'Y'
```

The BETWEEN operator is inclusive so will include the dates above see here  - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749615/does-ms-sql-servers-between-include-the-range-boundaries)

EDIT: Removed incorrect statement about how the BETWEEN operator works

Comment: This answer was added before the OP added his SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Because of your Datetime
Try this :

```
 select * 
    from mytable 
    where convert(date,paid_on,103) between '2014-12-08' and '2014-12-10' 
      and Status in ('Open') and Value='Y'
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
SELECT 
     Id
    ,Status
    ,Value
    ,CreatedDateTime 
FROM <table>
WHERE
    CreatedDateTime <= '2014-12-08 14:03:10.100'
    AND CreatedDateTime >= '2014-12-10 14:03:10.100'
    AND Status = 'Open'
    AND Value = 'Y'
```