# What's wrong with this SQL syntax to select data between two dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

This query was working before, but maybe I changed it somehow..

```
select * from completed_games where date BETWEEN 2015-02-22 00:00:00 AND 2015-02-28 00:00:00
```

Why would this query not work, and how can I properly write it?

Error:

```
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00 AND 2015-02-28 00:00:00' at line 1
```

Comment: Please note that it's better to explicitly use comparison operators for a date range (rather than 'between',) since it's easier to know whether it includes the date or not by looking for an equal sign.

Comment: @mbomb007 Easier for who?

Comment: @Strawberry See here, `between` is not recommended. http://stackoverflow.com/a/749663/2415524

Comment: @mbomb007 I think that's a spurious argument. As one of the commentator's suggests, it's like pointing out that 10.2 is not between 5 and 10. And the example provided is nonsensical. I don't understand why its attracted so much rep.

Comment: It's definitely a readability issue. Why not be clear and use standard comparison operators. Also, funny that you couldn't even come up with your own counter-argument.

Answer (score 2):

Your dates are not valid. You need to enclose them between quotes.

```
select *
from completed_games
where date BETWEEN '2015-02-22 00:00:00' AND '2015-02-28 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around your date strings:

```
select * 
from completed_games 
where date BETWEEN '2015-02-22 00:00:00' 
    AND '2015-02-28 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to check a time you can even do the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM completed_games 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2015-02-22' AND '2015-02-28'
```

Tip: Try to use backticks (`) around keywords or special chars.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, the best answer.

Comment: I think this a question about MySQL.

Comment: MySQL uses backticks instead of square brackets.