# SQL BETWEEN comment is not working if start and end date are same

Tags: sql

Query

`$dateCond = " AND TIMESTAMP BETWEEN $startTime AND $endTime";`

```
SELECT TITLE, PID, TYPE
  FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW
 WHERE $dateCond
 GROUP BY TITLE, PID, TYPE 
 ORDER BY TITLE DESC`
```

This query works fine if start and end date are different. It fails when both are same. Is there any wrong in my query.

Or do i need to try

`$dateCond = " AND TIMESTAMP >= $startTime AND TIMESTAMP <= $endTime";`

Comment: When you say "fail" do you mean it gives an error or just returns nothing? If it's an error please post the error.

Comment: Its display 'No result found'. But it as result

Comment: Can you post the values of $startime and $endtime please.

Comment: According to [other users observation](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/160191/why-is-sqls-between-inclusive-rather-than-half-open) the SQL standard dictates the BETWEEN operator to be inclusive. What you see here is apparently a bug in your DBMS. What database is it?

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? Do SELECT DISTINCT instead if that's what you want!

Answer (score 0):

`Between` include the edges
Lets say your start and end date are 30/12/2015 00:00:00
so only on this specific second (or even by same millisecond) you will get the result

> Or do i need to try
>
> $dateCond = " AND TIMESTAMP >= $startTime AND TIMESTAMP <= $endTime";

This will give you the same results as using between

For more information: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749615/does-ms-sql-servers-between-include-the-range-boundaries)

Answer (score 0):

remove `AND` from this declaration 
`$datecond=" AND TIMESTAMP BETWEEN $startTime AND $endTime";` 
unless it result in sql error as the query became `where AND ...` this is wrong syntax, or else you can us `1=1` 
`$dateCond = " AND TIMESTAMP BETWEEN $startTime AND $endTime";.`

Comment: "This query works fine...", It's seem @drup write only the relevant code, but forgot remove the AND