# Retrieving data for the past 30 minutes

Tags: sql-server, ssms

anyone know how to retrieve data from the database within the past 30 minutes. I tried solution such as DateTime >= DateADD(MINUTE,-30,GETDATE()) but does not help as after 30 minutes i still updating and also replacing the DateTime Column.

Comment: which database are you using.

Comment: Microsoft SQL database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749615/does-ms-sql-servers-between-include-the-range-boundaries/749663 try this post

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
select * from ablename where DateTime >= DateADD(MINUTE,-30,GETDATE()) and DateTime<getdate()
```

Comment: I tried to send values for the past 7 minutes and it return nothing when it is executed