# How to get the average maximum value between rows with a given step?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I need to get in columns the average maximum value between two rows with n steps. If the step is 6 (n = 6), I need to find out the average maximum value between 1 and 6 (not inclusive) rows, then between 6 and 12 (not inclusive), and so on. Both the step and the count of rows can be different.

```
|id|eventDate |  x  | y |
-------------------------
|1 |10.10.2021| 0.33|0.4|
-------------------------
|2 |10.11.2021| 0.34|0.5|
-------------------------
|3 |10.12.2021| 0.35|0.6|
-------------------------
|4 |10.13.2021| 0.36|0.7|
-------------------------
|5 |10.14.2021| 0.37|0.8|
-------------------------
```

Step = 3 (n = 3) The result should be

```
|id|eventDate |        x              |          y           |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|3 |10.12.2021| avr between id 1 and 3|avr between id 1 and 3|
--------------------------------------------------------------
|5 |10.14.2021| avr between id 3 and 5|avr between id 3 and 5|
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The "result" you're asking for doesn't include an average number.  By non-inclusive do you mean n=6 would average 2 -> 5, not 1 and 6?  Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: if n = 6 the average value in the range of lines 1,2,3,4,5,6 will be calculated

Comment: So they're inclusive, just like the BETWEEN command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749615/does-ms-sql-servers-between-include-the-range-boundaries/749663 "The BETWEEN operator is inclusive."  "BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression."
"

Answer (score 0):

If you want SQL to attempt to return groups you can use something like NTILE if your DBMS supports it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

I've added a 6th row to make the groups equal.  In your question you specified you wanted to group 1-3 and 3-5 (inclusively), which would double-up the averaging row 3.  I'm not sure if that's what you intended.

This works in MSSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(
    ID INT,
    eventDate DATE,
    x NUMERIC(3,2),
    y NUMERIC(3,2)
)

DECLARE @Step INT = 3

INSERT INTO #Temp
VALUES 
(1,'10.10.2021',0.33,0.4),
(2,'10.11.2021',0.34,0.5),
(3,'10.12.2021',0.35,0.6),
(4,'10.13.2021',0.36,0.7),
(5,'10.14.2021',0.37,0.8),
(6,'10.15.2021',0.38,0.9)

DECLARE @GroupCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp) / @Step

SELECT MAX(ID) as ID, MAX(eventDate) as eventDate, AVG(x) as AvgX, AVG(y) as AvgY
FROM(
    SELECT *, NTILE(@GroupCount) OVER(ORDER BY ID) Grp
    FROM #Temp
) as t
GROUP BY t.Grp
DROP TABLE #Temp
```

| ID | eventDate | AvgX | AvgY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-10-12 | 0.340000 | 0.500000 |
| 6 | 2021-10-15 | 0.370000 | 0.800000 |

Otherwise you'll probably have to resort to a CURSOR or WHILE loop.

Comment: will this work if instead of id there is a generated UUID?

Comment: Yes, even using the date should be fine.

Comment: A query of this kind partially solves the problem, but unnecessary rows remain
===============================================
SELECT
    eventDate,
    avg(x) OVER (ORDER BY eventDate ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avrX,
    avg(y) OVER (ORDER BY eventDate ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avrY FROM table  ORDER BY eventDate

Comment: i work with clickhouse

Comment: Oh, then I assume you'll need to use whatever loop-like functions they have available.  Clickhouse isn't actually SQL so I'm not sure. "ClickHouse supports an extended SQL-like language that includes arrays and nested data structures".  I've updated the tags on your question so hopefully somebody with experience using it can help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you want your bands to overlap in the first/last rows. I suspect you don't. It's also not clear what you mean by "average maximum".

So if you use `row_number()` to associate a unique group number to each row I think you'll be able to aggregate.

```
with data as (
    select *,
        (row_number() over (order by eventDate) - 1)
          / groupSize /* aka n? */ as grp /* integer division */
    from tbl
)
select
    min(id) as min_id, min(eventDate) as min_eventDate,
    avg(x) as avg_x, avg(y) as avg_y
from data
group by grp;
```